# Rewrite 2d array, which contains only some keys

Tags: php, arrays

I am using Animate.css for Bootstrap carousel and I need to sort the animations.

I have made an array called $anims, which contains all the animations. I want to make a new variable which contains only entrance animations, for example. So this is my array.

```
$anims = array(
    "Bouncing Entrances" => array(
        "bounceIn",
        "bounceInDown",
        ....
    ),
    "Bouncing Exits" => array(
        "bounceOut",
        "bounceOutDown",
        ....
    ),
    "Fading Entrances" => array(
        "fadeIn",
        "fadeInDown",
        ....
    ),

    ......
)
$enrtyAnims = ...
?>
```

After processing it should look like that:

```
$anims = array(
    "Bouncing Entrances" => array(
        "bounceIn",
        "bounceInDown",
        ....
    ),
    "Fading Entrances" => array(
        "fadeIn",
        ....
    )
)
```

But I don't have any idea how to do it with the keys. **I want to be able to say I want new array with keys X and Y and it makes it.**

Comment: is this exemplary key `"EntrancesAnim"` should be valid in your case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function with third flag parameter along with the flag `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` so your code looks like as

```
$result_array = array_filter($anims,function($k){ 
                     return (strpos($k,"Entrances") !== false);
                },ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

> Note: Flags as third parameter are introduced in PHP versions >= 5.6.0

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/XJ2A9)

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTsarev, I just forgot to mention that within notes

Answer (score 1):

Access the desired elements by key and create a new array using these items, like this:

```
$anims = array(
    'Bouncing Entrances' => $anims['Bouncing Entrances'],
    'Fading Entrances' => $anims['Fading Entrances'],
    // ...
);
```

EDIT: forgot to preserve the keys.
If there's a certain pattern by which you want to filter the animations, you can use `array_filter()` function, like @Uchiha said.

Comment: Would that have the same structure as the other array or it will insert just the values?